# Beginner in C, error with libcurl

Tags: c, variables, libcurl

I just started learning **C**, and I want to create a small text based browser. When the program starts, it says "Enter the URL:", and then I use `scanf()`, to grab user's input. When it grabs it, it's supposed to say "Loading {USER_INPUT}...", but instead it says "Loading {FIRST_LETTER_OF_USERS_INPUT}...", in which case it's `h`. I am sure it's something wrong with declaring variables. Here is my full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
 
int main(void)
{

char urlinput;
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    printf("\nEnter a URL to go to: ");
    scanf("%c", &urlinput);
    printf("\nLoading %c...\n", urlinput);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, urlinput);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(res != CURLE_OK) fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: As you *are* a beginner, maybe it's a bit too early for you to play with third-party libraries, such as CURL. The problem here is that urlinput should not be a `char`, but a `char*` or `char` array.
Also, you should call `scanf` with a "%s" format, which reads a string, not a "%c", which reads a single char.

Comment: Hmm interesting, you should say it as your answer so I can accept it thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an array of chars (string):

```
char urlinput[100];
```

and your scanf:

```
scanf("%s", urlinput);
```

Comment: Ok it worked, thanks. How do I make it so after it displays the HTML, it sort of restarts the program and makes me go back to the input?

Comment: You would need something like an infinite loop in your whole program, and then you just `break` when you want to stop. You can ask "do you want to continue?" `scanf("%c", &flag)` and `if(flag=='n') break;`

Comment: How do I combine variables, for example, `function(blabla, myvar.myvar2)`? That's in PHP, is `C the same?

Comment: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.com/clean_html.php?key=uoeno&url=" & urlinput);` that's what I use but it gives me some binary error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that urlinput should not be a char, but a char* or char array. Also, you should call scanf with a "%s" format, which reads a string, not a "%c", which reads a single char.

The problem is not related to CURL, anyway.

Here is a simpler, more correct sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char input[1024];

    printf("Enter a URL to go to: ");
    scanf("%1023[^\n]", input);
    //Or: scanf("%1023s", input);
    printf("Loading %s...\n", input);

    return 0;
}
```

The difference between "s" and "[^\n]" formats is that "s" stops at the first space, whereas "[^\n]" reads a whole line. Since URL syntax forbids spaces, it makes no difference in your case.

I said *more* correct, because the code I posted is still flawed: it lacks error checking and does not handle cases where the input is longer than 1024 characters (it will not crash,  thanks to the 1023 width I specified in the format, but will silently discard characters past the 1023-th, that's not so polite).

For more information, refer to the C standard, or to the manual of the C library you are using. Here is [GNU C](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatted-Input.html#Formatted-Input), and here is [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y6s16x1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: This is nice too, but a little bit complicated for me. I don't need any error handling at the moment I just need to get hang of C. Thanks for your help, I'll use your part whenever I start understanding it xD.

Comment: As I said, while you get a hang on C, you should only use C, not CURL. The less you use, the easier the errors are to understand. When you're experienced enough to deal with vanilla C, you can add more complex stuff, like CURL or any other third-party library.